# If i not using v-for in flickity then carousel is working fine but if used then all item align verticaly

Tags: vue.js, flickity

When i am using carousel without `v-for` it is working fine but when i am using with `v-for` it align item vertically. I am putting code below:

```
<div class="main-carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell" v-for="item in TaskTypesList" :key="index">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `display: flex` on the parent element?

Comment: i tried then next and previous button is not working